# 403 Client HTTPError when trying to connect to Reddit via praw

Tags: python, reddit, praw

So I'm trying to develop a Bot that posts Game Day threads to the /r/KontinentalHL subreddit, but whenever I try to login I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "startBot.py", line 12, in <module>
    r.login(Username,Password)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 1230, in login
    self.request_json(self.config['login'], data=data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 161, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 510, in request_json
    response = self._request(url, params, data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 375, in _request
    _raise_response_exceptions(response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\praw\internal.py", line 172, in _raise_response_exceptions
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 808, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden
```

I'm certain my login details are correct, I'm confused! I'm probably being an idiot, but any help? Also when I try r.login() without parameters the program freezes after I input my username!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is most likely your user agent string. Try changing it to something either longer or without keywords like "scraping" or "bot".

Comment: I shudder to think how many more times I would've checked my client id and client secret, character by character, had I not discovered this answer. Thank you!!